# Can't install with pip: SSL error

Tags: windows-10, python, ssl, python3, pip

I'm new to coding and have recently started learning Python. Whenever I enter `pip install django` (for example), I get these error messages:

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))':/simple/django/`

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping`

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for django`

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping`

I get the same messages regardless of what I am installing. I have tried variant commands like `python -m pip install django==3.1.7`, but with no luck. I installed Python direct from the website and am using PyCharm. I can't really progress so would be very grateful for help!

Comment: What OS and what Python version do you use? The error looks like your Python/SSL libraries are too old.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm on Windows 10.0.19041, build 19041. I'm using Python 3.9.2.

Comment: pypi.org support TLS 1.2 + 1.3 therefore a TLS version problem should not be a problem on a direct connection. Is it possible that your system uses a proxy?

Comment: Definitely not, it's my own laptop. That has made me wonder though. I have been having a bunch of problems with my laptop recently, many of them with syncing it to my MS account. MS support reckoned it was to do with the laptop having moved to Win10 from Win8 rather than starting with it. Could that be causing the problems?

Comment: I have the exact same problem - both with my Python packages and my MS account. This is the first post I've come across which relates them. If anyone has any clues as to what could be wrong, it would massively help me. It's causing me quite serious problems!